# PowerShell .NET Mimic Windows default checkbox behaviour for treenodes

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, powershell

In our `Windows.Forms` form, we're trying to achieve the following:

1. Check/uncheck all the child nodes when you check/uncheck a parent node.
2. Auto check the parent node if all of its child nodes are checked.
3. Auto uncheck the parent node if one of its child node is unchecked.

**Test code:**

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$treeView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
$treeView.Dock = 'Fill'
$treeView.CheckBoxes = $true

$N1 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 1')
$N2 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 2')
$N3 = $treeView.Nodes.Add('Node 3')

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Node 1 Sub 1'
$newNode.Text = 'Node 1 Sub 1'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode)

$newNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.Name = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$newNode.Text = 'Node 1 Sub 2'
$N1.Nodes.Add($newNode) | Out-Null
# There can be deeper levels of treenodes

$TV_AfterCheck = {
    if($_.Node.Checked) {
        #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Node ' + $_.Node.Text + ' checked')
    }
    else {
        #[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Node ' + $_.Node.Text + ' unchecked')
    }
}

$treeView.Add_AfterCheck($TV_AfterCheck)
$form.Controls.Add($treeView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

The solution I found is tailored to another language, and I can't get it to work in PowerShell. There's a lot of information on this topic, but it's all in other programming languages.

**Solution in another language:**

```
Private Sub CheckChildNode(ByVal currNode As TreeNode)
'set the children check status to the same as the current node
Dim checkStatus As Boolean = currNode.Checked
For Each node As TreeNode In currNode.Nodes
node.Checked = checkStatus
CheckChildNode(node)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckParentNode(ByVal currNode As TreeNode)
Dim parentNode As TreeNode = currNode.Parent
If parentNode Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
parentNode.Checked = True
For Each node As TreeNode In parentNode.Nodes
If Not node.Checked Then
parentNode.Checked = False
Exit For
End If
Next
CheckParentNode(parentNode)
End Sub

Private Sub treeview_AfterCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles treeview.AfterCheck
RemoveHandler treeview.AfterCheck, AddressOf treeview_AfterCheck
CheckChildNode(e.Node)
CheckParentNode(e.Node)
AddHandler treeview.AfterCheck, AddressOf treeview_AfterCheck
End Sub
```

It would really be great if someone could help me pasting it together so it would work in PowerShell to. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is basically a rewrite of the VB.NET code you included:

You need to include the following functions:

```
function checkChildNode($node) {
 $checkStatus = $node.checked
  foreach ($n in $node.nodes) {
   $n.checked = $checkstatus
   checkChildNode($n)
  }
}

function checkParentNode($node) {
 $parent = $node.parent
 if($parent -eq $null) {
   return
 }
 $parent.checked = $true
 foreach ($n in $parent.nodes) {
    if(!$n.checked) {
      $parent.checked = $false
      break
    }  
  }
  checkparentNode($parent)
}
```

And change your event handler to be:

```
$TV_AfterCheck = {
    $treeView.Remove_AfterCheck($TV_AfterCheck)
    checkChildNode($_.node)
    checkParentNode($_.node)
    $treeView.Add_AfterCheck($TV_AfterCheck)
}
```

This will give you the behaviour you're after.

Comment: Thank you Arco444, it's almost perfect :) When I check 'Node 1' it does indeed check all it's sub nodes correctly. However, when I deselect only one sub node of 'Node 1' (Ex. Node 1 Sub 1'), they all get unchecked.

Comment: Perfect! Like a boss! Thank you Arco444 :)